# Как вывести сумму четных чисел от 10 до 40 циклом do-while на PHP

Tags: php, циклы, числа

Как вывести сумму четных чисел от 10 до 40 циклом do-while. Как исправить цикл чтобы он считал сумму четных чисел от 10 до 40.? Если число более от 10 до 40 выводится сумма четных чисел. Если число менее 10 и более 40 то выводится текст «Число должно быть больше 10 и не более 40».

```
<?php
$num = 22;    
if ($num >= 10 && $num <= 40) {            
 do {
 if ($num % 2 === 0) 
  echo "<br/>".$num; 
  } 
   while ( $num++ < 40 );
}   
else echo "Число должно быть больше 10 и не более 40"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$num = 28;
$sum = 0;
if($num >= 10 && $num <= 40) {
    echo "<b>Четные числа от $num до 40:</b> ";
    do {
        if($num % 2 == 0) {
            echo $num . ' ';
            $sum += $num;
        }
        $num++;
    }
    while ($num <= 40);
    echo "<br><b>Cумма четных чисел из заданного диапазона равна:</b> " . $sum;
} 
else {
    echo "Число должно быть больше 10 и не более 40";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $sum = 0;
    $num = 10;
    if ($num >= 10 && $num <= 40)
    {   
        do
        {
            if($num % 2 == 0)
            {
                echo $num."<br/>";
                $sum += $num;
            }
        $num++;
    }while($num<=40);
    echo $sum;
    else 
        echo "Число должно быть больше 10 и не более 40"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    $sum = 0;
    $num = 10;
    if ($num >= 10 && $num <= 40)
    {   
       while($num<=40){
            if($num % 2 == 0)
            {
                echo $num."<br/>";
                $sum += $num;

            }
          $num++;
       }

    }
    echo $sum;
    else 
        echo "Число должно быть больше 10 и не более 40"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

А еще лучше:

```
echo array_sum(range(10,40,2));
```

Или целиком:

```
echo ($num >= 10 && $num <= 40)? array_sum(range(10,40,2)) : 'Число должно быть';
```

Хотя тут просили через `do_while`, но ладно.